# How Many Circles Can Be Drawn That Are Tangent To Each Other?

Tags: geometry

I learned about the "Problem of Apollonius" in which three circles are drawn, and the task is to draw a fourth circle that is tangential to these three circles (it seems that if you "fix" these first three circles, there are many options for the fourth circle): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius

I was thinking about a "Generalized" version of this problem - if you were to first draw "n" number of circles, could we then determine if a circle exists that is tangential to all of these "n" circles?

I tried to read about this online and came across the following links:

- " A Theorem on Circle Configurations " : https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0706/0706.0372.pdf
- "Generalized Problem of Apollonius": https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.03090 (Russian)

However, I was not able to fully comprehend these links because my understanding of mathematics is insufficient and I also do not speak Russian.

Thus - can someone please help me understand: if you were to first draw "n" number of circles, could we then determine if a circle exists that is tangential to all of these "n" circles?  For example, if I "fixed" 27 circles - is there any way of knowing if a circle can be made that is tangential to all of these 27 circles?

Thanks!

Comment: One method is to choose three of the original circles, find their eight Apollonius circles, and see if any of those eight are tangential to all the other original circles

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket

Comment: I was looking at the Apollonian Gasket over here : https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jerzy-Kocik/publication/257298313/figure/fig4/AS:668691985346578@1536440001896/An-Apollonian-gasket-and-its-four-greatest-circles-smallest-curvatures.png

Comment: If you draw circles small enough - it looks like you can draw infinite circles that are tangential to a single circle?